# Darktable disable auto correction

Tags: photo-editing, darktable

I am using darktable for editing my RAW photos and am really a newbie.

When I open a new photo, some corrections are already applied, for instance "base curve", "sharpen" etc

Is there a way to disable them?

I know I can go back clicking on "original" in the history, but I would like to disable them.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "original" raw image that you can view on a monitor. The information in a raw file MUST be processed to be displayed as a viewable image. If you set darktable to show only the actual sensor data, you'll get what looks like a very dim B&W checkerboard with a very dim monochromatic image projected onto it.

Answer (score 5):

In lighttable mode, go to *preferences* > *processing*. Then, disable every "*auto apply*" option.

https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.6/preferences-settings/processing/

It still uses white-balance and automatic orientation with data from camera.

You may also edit module presets, and configure when they are applied automatically. But you cannot edit built-in presets.

https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.6/darkroom/processing-modules/presets/

EDIT: as @user10216038 already said. Demosaicing module is always applied too. Otherwise, there is no image to see from a raw file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minimum level of processing required to convert raw image data to what is generally recognized as an image. For example the raw data does not contain color "*pixels*", it is monochrome "*sensor elements*" from which color pixels must be constructed.

Unless you're doing low level coding on raw data, you almost certainly would find eliminating these base level processes to be counter productive.

Comment: oh, you're right! I forgot to mention demosaicing  is always applied. Otherwise it's impossible to see an image from a raw file.

Answer (score -2):

I found it. In Settings>Lighttable, use RAW instead of embedded JPG.